# HTML text input RegEx validation not working even with required attribute

Tags: javascript, regex, html

I am trying to have my dynamically generated text inputs only allow for digits and an optional decimal point in between. I am using the attribute but the inputs are still unresponsive to the RegEx.

```
var howMuch = $("<input>").attr("type", "text").attr("name", "howMuch").attr("pattern", "([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)").prop("required", true);
```

The HTML generates like so: [HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izH1z.png)

**PLEASE do not mark this question as duplicate, none of the existing similar answers are already using the 'required' attribute**

Comment: Should be `"([0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?)"` to account for string metacharacter interpretation. `"([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)"` is exactly the same as `"([0-9]+(.[0-9]+)?)"`.

Comment: Neither of those expressions solved my issue. Alphabetical inputs are still being added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointy answer applies.
Also, `pattern` attributes only works at form validation time. In other words, user is able to type in whatever he wants. Only when he presses submit, `pattern` attribute is taken into consideration.
If you want a realtime feedback to user you should listen to `change` events and manually trigger the form `validate` method. Or you can use the `keydown` event to prevent some characters to be accepted as input.

Comment: Think I'm going to use keydown. Thank you for your answer!